# can LSF be used to run each job on a seperate vm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, lsf

Based on documentation LSF is used mainly for HPC (High performance computing). Its resource connector (LSF resource connector) is meant to borrow VMs from resource provider (e.g AWS). This means LSF will launch an instance and run jobs that you submit. Based on the workload it can launch many instances (< "maxNumber") and run the jobs.

My question is:

I want to run jobs on separate VMs (no matter the load on them).

- 2 of the jobs are services (*service A, service B*) that must be run on different VMs and must be used by other/client VMs  (count of client VMs can vary)
- one of client VMs will be the master and run commands on the rest of the client VMs. Commands use *service A, service B* mentioned above.
- So I also need some kind of interconnection between the VMs.

Is LSF suitable for such type of configurations/cases or I'd better find another solution than LSF??